# »composer create-project« - How to know afterwards which version of the original project was used?

Tags: php, composer-php, semantic-versioning, infrastructure

Most PHP frameworks offer a skeleton or bare distribution to create a new instance. When I create a new project based on such a skeleton project I may run `composer create-project foo/some-framework my-new-project`.

How do I know, at a much later point in time, which version of the framework was used originally for my project?

Lets say I composed the project with version 3.0.0 of the framework. Some month later the framework is available in version 5.1.0. I want to upgrade now, but which version did I use… was it version 3.0.0 or 4.0.0 or 4.2.0?

What is the best practice for this situation? Document the version into some extra file? Always urge the framework to have a version stored in a file?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for composer you have composer.lock file and usually you can look into this file what's the version of installed packages for example in one of my projects in `composer.lock` I have:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/framework",
    "version": "v5.5.14",
```

so I know version 5.5.14 is installed.

Obviously for Laravel you can also run:

```
php artisan --version
```

to get Laravel version or open `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php` file and you will see there:

```
const VERSION = '5.5.14';
```

About different versions when installing via composer you can specify version you would like to install like this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.3.*
```

so in above case you decide you want to install 5.3 version (at the moment there is Laravel 5.5 already released)

Comment: »laravel/framework« is a dependency of »laravel/laravel« and therefore present in the ```composer``` files. Regarding your example my question is however: How do you know, at a later point in time, that you used version 5.3.x of »laravel/laravel« to create the project?

Comment: Well, if you created Laravel 5.3 app, you will have Laravel framework 5.3 as dependency so you will know this is Laravel 5.3 app, won't you? In `composer.json` you will see framework in 5.3 version and if you want you can add your app version also in description for example of `composer.json` so you will really know this :) You can also add this to `readme.md` of your project.